# php funtction to display entire mysql table when no specific id selected

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have 3 functions where objective is to diplay list of

> Car Make
> Car Model
> price

which is working fine when a car make is selected and corresponding model and price are displayed, but when no car make is selected the i wish to show the entire database list of all car makes, models and price

Unfortunately its displaying message in that scenario as no car available as given in function  3.

```
else{  
        $list.='No Car available';
    }
```

This $list should propage entire database of car make, model, price instead of same.

I really dont know on how to show entire database list of make, model and price when no make is selected.

Any guide on how to achieve in

```
    public function getCatName($id){
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query = "SELECT cat_name from #__newcar_categories where id='".$id."'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadAssoc();
    return $row['cat_name'];
}

public function getCatPath($id,$show_link=0){
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query = "SELECT cat_name ,id  ,cat_parent from #__newcar_categories where id='".$id."'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $total = $db->loadResult();
    $pageNav = new JPagination( $total, $limitstart, $limit );
    $db->setQuery( $query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('limit') );

    $row = $db->loadAssoc();
    if($row['cat_parent']!="0"){
        $sql1 = "SELECT cat_name , id   from #__newcar_categories where id='".$row['cat_parent']."'";
        $database->setQuery($sql1);
        $row1 = $database->loadAssoc();
        $list=' <a href="index.php?option=com_newcar&view=category&Itemid=2&id='.$row1['id'].'">'.$row1['cat_name'].'</a>';
        if($show_link==1){
            $list.=' <a href="index.php?option=com_newcar&view=subcategory&Itemid=2&id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</a>';
        }else{
            $list.=' '.$row['cat_name'];
        }
        return $list;
    }else{
        return $row['cat_name'];
    }
    
}

public function loadMainCat($brand,$Carmodel){
    $mainframe =JFactory::getApplication();
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    
    if($brand!=""){
        $query = "SELECT * from #__newcar_categories where id ='".$brand."' and state='1' order by cat_sorder";
    }else{
        $query = "Select *  from #__newcar_categories Where 1 and state='1' Order By cat_sorder ";
    }

    $db->setQuery($query);  
    $db->setQuery( $query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('limit') );
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    
    $list="";
    $flg=0;
    if($rows){
    $id='';
    $Desc=$this->loadSubCatDescr($id);
    $list.='<div class="listing-box">
            <div class="listing-box-left">
            <h4>Car Make</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="listing-box-middle">
           <h4> Model</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="listing-box-right">
            <h4><a href="#" onMouseover="ddrivetip(\'Ex-Showroom Delhi\')"; onMouseout="hideddrivetip()" style="color:#424141">Base Price Delhi</a></h4>
            </div>';
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $item_id = $this->getItemIdByName($row->cat_name);
            if($row->cat_image!=""){
                $img = "uploads/categories/".$row->cat_image;
            }
            if($flg==0){
                $cls="";
                $flg=1;
            }else{
                $cls="";
                $flg=0;
            }
            
            $list.='<div class="listing-box-left"><p>'.$row->cat_name.'</p></div>
                    <div class="listing-box-middle">'.$this->loadSubCat($row->id,$Carmodel).'</div>';
        }
    $list.='</div>';
    }else{  
        $list.='No Car available';
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Is this Joomla?

Comment: Yes its Joomla only.

Comment: When you post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange, you have a much better chance of receiving support from someone who has actually used Joomla.